# How do I change the value of a variable in python tkinter based on drop down selection?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, drop-down-menu, variable-assignment

So I'm brand new to coding in general and I'm trying to create a GUI that returns the number of players per team, number of teams in a match, and average match length based on a dropdown menu selection.

I've tried using an if else statement for all of the menu options but can't figure out how to reassign variables within the if else statement. Is there a better way to do this?

```
drop = OptionMenu(infoWindow, variable, "League of Legends", "Overwatch", "Valorant", "Smash Bros", "Rainbow 6", command=gameInformation)
```

```
def gameInformation(selection):
    if selection == "League of Legends":
        global perTeams = 1
        global sizeTeams = 2
        global matchLength = 3
    elif selection == "Overwatch"
        global perTeams = 4
        global sizeTeams = 5
        global matchLength = 6
```

...and so on for each game. Any advice is appreciated! Full code below:

```
from tkinter import *

#start window

start_window = Tk()

screen_width = start_window.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = start_window.winfo_screenheight()

start_window.title("AU Student Center Esports Scheduler")
start_window.geometry("%dx%d" % (screen_width, screen_height))
start_window['background']='#e87722'

lbl = Label(start_window,
            text = "AU Student Center Esports Scheduling App",
            font=("Davis", 50),
            bg='#e87722',
            fg='#0c2340')
lbl.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.4, anchor=CENTER)

def gameInformation(selection):
    if selection == "League of Legends":
        global perTeams = 1
        global sizeTeams = 2
        global matchLength = 3
    elif selection == "Overwatch"
        global perTeams = 4
        global sizeTeams = 5
        global matchLength = 6


def openInfoWindow():
    infoWindow = Toplevel(start_window)
    infoWindow.title('Tournament Information')
    infoWindow.geometry("800x800")
    infoWindow['background']='#0c2340'
    gameSelect_lbl = Label(infoWindow, 
           text = "What Kind of Tournament?",
           font = ("Davis", 25),
           bg='#0c2340',
           fg='#e87722')
    gameSelect_lbl.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, anchor=CENTER)
    variable = StringVar(infoWindow)
    variable.set("League of Legends")
    drop = OptionMenu(infoWindow, variable, "League of Legends", "Overwatch", "Valorant", "Smash Bros", "Rainbow 6", command=gameInformation)
    drop.config(bg='#e87722')
    drop.config(fg='#0c2340')
    drop["menu"].config(bg='#e87722')
    drop["menu"].config(fg='#0c2340')
    drop.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor=CENTER)
    sizeTeams_lbl = Label(infoWindow,
            text = "Team Size: ",
            font=("Davis", 15),
            bg='#e87722',
            fg='#0c2340')
    sizeTeams_lbl.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.3, anchor=W)
    perTeams_lbl = Label(infoWindow,
            text = "Teams per Match: ",
            font=("Davis", 15),
            bg='#e87722',
            fg='#0c2340')
    perTeams_lbl.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.35, anchor=W)
    matchLength_lbl = Label(infoWindow,
            text = "Avg. Match Length (minutes): ",
            font=("Davis", 15),
            bg='#e87722',
            fg='#0c2340')
    matchLength_lbl.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.4, anchor=W)
    sizeTeams_gen = Label(infoWindow,
            text = sizeTeams,
            font=("Davis", 15),
            bg='#0c2340',
            fg='#e87722')
    sizeTeams_gen.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.3, anchor=W)
    perTeams_gen = Label(infoWindow,
            text = perTeams,
            font=("Davis", 15),
            bg='#0c2340',
            fg='#e87722')
    perTeams_gen.place(relx=0.28, rely=0.35, anchor=W)
    matchLength_gen = Label(infoWindow,
            text = matchLength,
            font=("Davis", 15),
            bg='#0c2340',
            fg='#e87722')
    matchLength_gen.place(relx=0.41, rely=0.4, anchor=W)
    
btn = Button(start_window, 
             text = "Click to Begin", 
             font=("Davis", 25),
             bg = "#0c2340", 
             fg = "#e87722", 
             command = openInfoWindow)
btn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor=CENTER)

start_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you need to declare a variable as *global* and assign a value to it in two lines instead of one:

```py
# initialize those variables
perTeams = sizeTeams = matchLength = 0

def gameInformation(selection):
    global perTeams, sizeTeams, matchLength
    if selection == "League of Legends":
        perTeams = 1
        sizeTeams = 2
        matchLength = 3
    elif selection == "Overwatch"
        perTeams = 4
        sizeTeams = 5
        matchLength = 6
    elif ...
        ...
```

However updating those variables will not update the text of those corresponding labels, you need to update them explicitly:

```py
# initialize those variables
perTeams = sizeTeams = matchLength = 0

def gameInformation(selection):
    global perTeams, sizeTeams, matchLength
    if selection == "League of Legends":
        perTeams = 1
        sizeTeams = 2
        matchLength = 3
    elif selection == "Overwatch"
        perTeams = 4
        sizeTeams = 5
        matchLength = 6
    elif ...
        ...

    # update labels
    sizeTeams_gen.config(text=sizeTeams)
    perTeams_gen.config(text=perTeams)
    matchLength_gen.config(text=matchLength)

def openInfoWindow():
    # need to declare the following labels as global variables
    # otherwise they cannot be accessed inside gameInformation()
    global perTeams_gen, sizeTeams_gen, matchLength_gen

    ...
```